# No connection between host PC and mbed via Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, mbed, tcp-ip

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

// Network interface
EthernetInterface net;

TCPSocket listener;
TCPSocket* client;

DigitalOut led1(LED1);

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);


// Socket demo
int main()
{

    int remaining;
    int rcount;
    char *p;
    char *buffer = new char[256];
    nsapi_size_or_error_t result;

    int n = net.set_network("192,168,10,101","255,255,255,0","192,168,10,10");
    pc.printf("\n Success? %d\n", n);
    net.connect();

    listener.open(&net);
    listener.bind(80);

    listener.listen(1);

    client = listener.accept(NULL);
    client->set_timeout(1000);

    led1 = 0;
    while(1) {

        int remaining = 256;
        int rcount = 0;
        p = buffer;

        while (remaining > 0 && 0 < (result = client->recv(buffer, remaining))) {
            p += result;
            rcount += result;
            remaining -= result;
        }

        if (result == 0) { //Peer has shutdown connection
            client->close(); //close socket;

            client = listener.accept(NULL); //block again until new connection comes through
            client->set_timeout(1000);
        }


        if (result == NSAPI_ERROR_TIMEOUT ) { //Assume connection has been lost
            client->close(); //close socket;

            client = listener.accept(NULL); //block again until new connection comes through
            client->set_timeout(1000);

        }






    }


}
```

I'm trying to establish a connection between my mbed and PC via TCP, using Teraterm.

The host PC has an Ethernet cable connected to the breakout board I've wired to my mbed. I've changed the localhost settings so that only IPv4 is selected, and chosen a random static IP, to disable DHCP. Subnet mask has been set to 255.255.255.0 and random IP (192.168.10.10) for Gateway.

When trying to connect to the mbed with Teraterm (Service: other, Protocol: IPv4, host: 80), an "Invalid host" error appears.

I'm new to networking, so don't really know where the problem lies, although I do have some suspicions.

1. Are the IP addresses parsed in the correct format? The mbed documentation (https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.8/reference/ethernet.html) isn't clear at all on this.
2. Is the gateway something I can choose to set, or is this automatically assigned by the host PC?
3. Do I need to disable wireless?

I'm using the Sparkfun Ethernet breakout board, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you need an Ethernet Crossover Cable?? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: @ScottSeidman, Just tried that and still no luck.

Comment: Do you have an mbed board with Ethernet which you could try my code on? Not sure if the problem is with the mbed code or the configuration on the PC

Comment: Nope, sorry, but I don't use that board.

Comment: Do you have any comment on the IP format?

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid you'll have to wait for someone to answer.

Comment: Why are you using `,` as the separator in your IP addresses?! It should be `.`. Also you cannot pick a 'random' IP for the gateway. It should be the address of your computer. It would be much easier to just enable 'network sharing' to the Ethernet port where you connect the Mbed board and it'll get an IP address automatically through DHCP.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I’ve made the changes you suggested, as well as using a crossover Ethernet cable, and connection has been established. The Mbed documentation wasn’t particularly clear on the format IPs should have. I think in the previous libraries “,” was used to separate.

Comment: What I did notice though is that the first connection made to the Mbed is very slow (up to 10 secs), where as the following ones are virtually instant. There are also times when the connection is refused or times out. Can you explain this?